# Display total number of posts with certain criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm attempting to filter through data in my collection, but I can not seem to figure out how to accomplish displaying

- Number of total "*approved*" posts:
      Posts with `customer_approved` and `manager_approved` values equal to 1
- Number of "*pending*" posts:
      `customer_approved` or `manager_approved` (or both) equal to 0
- Number of "*rejected*" posts:
      `customer_approved` or `manager_approved` (or both) equal to -1

It seems so simple yet attempting to accomplish filtering data in Backbone is challenging for me.

I have attempted to apply logic in my views and my HTML without luck.

Here's my data/collection:

```
var ListItemCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    baseUrl: '/api/get_accounts',
    url: '/api/get_accounts',
    model: ListItemModel,
    total: 0,
    // Sample data
    TESTDATA: {"status":"ok","posts":[{"id":"1","schedule":"2020-0417 17:00:00","utc_offset":"420","project_id":"1","network":"facebook","network_name":"TestFacebookPage","network_thumb":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17634406_1854330461448271_6787736791983791423_n.jpg?oh=e4c3a3573c0fc59359422cfd66a3865a&oe=598721E7","message":"Test Post 1 (just text, approved)","data":[],"customer_approved":"1","manager_approved":"1","rejection_message":"","created_at":"2020-0413 17:41:03","created_by":"admin","created_by_id":"1","created_by_name":"John Admin"},{"id":"2","schedule":"2020-0419 19:00:00","project_id":"1","network":"facebook","network_name":"TestFacebookPage","network_thumb":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17634406_1854330461448271_6787736791983791423_n.jpg?oh=e4c3a3573c0fc59359422cfd66a3865a&oe=598721E7","message":"Test Post 2 (text with image, approved)  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.","data":{"pictures":["https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C9T6n0UUwAAOBaU.jpg"],"image_added":"true","picture":"https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C9T6n0UUwAAOBaU.jpg","type":"photo"},"customer_approved":"1","manager_approved":"1","rejection_message":"","rejection_message_manager":"","created_at":"2020-0413 17:42:34","created_by":"admin","created_by_id":"1","created_by_name":"John Admin"},{"id":"3","schedule":"2020-0421 22:00:00","network":"facebook","network_name":"TestFacebookPage","network_thumb":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17634406_1854330461448271_6787736791983791423_n.jpg?oh=e4c3a3573c0fc59359422cfd66a3865a&oe=598721E7","message":"Test Post 3 (link, approved) http://www.adultswim.com/videos/rick-and-morty/","data":{"image_added":"true","pictures":["http://i.cdn.turner.com/adultswim/big/img/2015/07/17/Rick%26MortyS02_fbsearchTn.jpg"],"picture":"http://i.cdn.turner.com/adultswim/big/img/2015/07/17/Rick%26MortyS02_fbsearchTn.jpg","link":"http://www.adultswim.com/videos/rick-and-morty/","name":"Watch Rick and Morty on Adult Swim","caption":"www.adultswim.com","description":"Every episode of Rick and Morty is now on AdultSwim.com for free. Rick is a mad scientist who drags his grandson, Morty, on crazy sci-fi adventures. Their escapades often have potentially harmful consequences for their family and the rest of the world. Join Rick and Morty on AdultSwim.com as they trek through alternate dimensions, explore alien planets, and terrorize Jerry, Beth, and Summer.","domain":"www.adultswim.com","type":"link"},"customer_approved":"1","manager_approved":"1","rejection_message":"","created_at":"2020-0413 17:43:29","created_by":"admin","created_by_id":"1","created_by_name":"John Admin"},{"id":"4","schedule":"2020-0424 17:00:00","network":"facebook","network_name":"TestFacebookPage","network_thumb":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17634406_1854330461448271_6787736791983791423_n.jpg?oh=e4c3a3573c0fc59359422cfd66a3865a&oe=598721E7","message":"Test Post 4 (text, pending)","data":[],"customer_approved":"0","manager_approved":"1","rejection_message":"","created_at":"2020-0413 17:43:48","created_by":"admin","created_by_id":"1","created_by_name":"John Admin"},{"id":"5","schedule":"2020-0426 19:00:00","network":"facebook","network_name":"TestFacebookPage","network_thumb":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17634406_1854330461448271_6787736791983791423_n.jpg?oh=e4c3a3573c0fc59359422cfd66a3865a&oe=598721E7","message":"Test Post 5 (picture, pending)","data":[],"customer_approved":"0","manager_approved":"1","rejection_message":"","created_at":"2020-0413 17:44:03","created_by":"admin","created_by_id":"1","created_by_name":"John Admin"},{"id":"6","schedule":"2020-0428 21:00:00","network":"facebook","network_name":"TestFacebookPage","network_thumb":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17634406_1854330461448271_6787736791983791423_n.jpg?oh=e4c3a3573c0fc59359422cfd66a3865a&oe=598721E7","message":"Test Post 6 (link, pending) https://www.reddit.com/","data":{"image_added":"true","pictures":["https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/2Hwaff37fC4f37j-3orrbjVAOVBChqbdm_dXeIhjlNw.jpg"],"picture":"https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/2Hwaff37fC4f37j-3orrbjVAOVBChqbdm_dXeIhjlNw.jpg","link":"https://www.reddit.com/","name":"reddit: the front page of the internet","caption":"www.reddit.com","description":"reddit: the front page of the internet","domain":"www.reddit.com","type":"link"},"customer_approved":"0","manager_approved":"1","rejection_message":"","created_at":"2020-0413 17:44:19","created_by":"admin","created_by_id":"1","created_by_name":"John Admin"}],"total":"6"},

    initialize: function(models, options) {
      this.total = this.TESTDATA.total;
      this.reset(this.TESTDATA.posts);
         console.log(this.models);
    }

});
```

Comment: While querying to DB only you can restrict that or loop it and add it to new collection...

Answer (score 0):

To filter out only posts which are both manager approved and customer approved, try using [underscore filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter):

```
var approved = _.filter(this.models, function(post){ 
    return post.get("manager_approved") === "1" && post.get("customer_approved") === "1";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Backbone proxies a number of functions from Underscore on collections, one of them being [`_.countBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#countBy) :

> **countBy** *_.countBy(list, iteratee, [context])*
>   Sorts a list into groups and returns a count for the number of objects in each group.
>   Similar to groupBy, but instead of returning a list of values, returns
>   a count for the number of values in that group.

It means that you can group your models by your states and get the count for each bucket.

With a slightly modified definition for your collection

```
var ListItemModel = Backbone.Model.extend();
var ListItemCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: ListItemModel,
    total: 0,

    parse: function(data) {
        // parse lets you reinterpret your data
        this.total = data.total;
        return data.posts;
    }
});
```

you can then get a count for each state with

```
var c = new ListItemCollection(TESTDATA, {parse: true});
var states = c.countBy(function(model) {
    var manager = +model.get("manager_approved"), 
    customer = +model.get("customer_approved");

    if ((manager === -1) || (customer === -1)) return 'rejected';
    if ((manager === 1) && (customer === 1)) return 'approved';
    return 'pending';
});
```

And a demo

```js
var TESTDATA = {"status":"ok","posts":[{"id":"1","schedule":"2020-0417 17:00:00","utc_offset":"420","project_id":"1","network":"facebook","network_name":"TestFacebookPage","network_thumb":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17634406_1854330461448271_6787736791983791423_n.jpg?oh=e4c3a3573c0fc59359422cfd66a3865a&oe=598721E7","message":"Test Post 1 (just text, approved)","data":[],"customer_approved":"1","manager_approved":"1","rejection_message":"","created_at":"2020-0413 17:41:03","created_by":"admin","created_by_id":"1","created_by_name":"John Admin"},{"id":"2","schedule":"2020-0419 19:00:00","project_id":"1","network":"facebook","network_name":"TestFacebookPage","network_thumb":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17634406_1854330461448271_6787736791983791423_n.jpg?oh=e4c3a3573c0fc59359422cfd66a3865a&oe=598721E7","message":"Test Post 2 (text with image, approved)  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.","data":{"pictures":["https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C9T6n0UUwAAOBaU.jpg"],"image_added":"true","picture":"https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C9T6n0UUwAAOBaU.jpg","type":"photo"},"customer_approved":"1","manager_approved":"1","rejection_message":"","rejection_message_manager":"","created_at":"2020-0413 17:42:34","created_by":"admin","created_by_id":"1","created_by_name":"John Admin"},{"id":"3","schedule":"2020-0421 22:00:00","network":"facebook","network_name":"TestFacebookPage","network_thumb":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17634406_1854330461448271_6787736791983791423_n.jpg?oh=e4c3a3573c0fc59359422cfd66a3865a&oe=598721E7","message":"Test Post 3 (link, approved) http://www.adultswim.com/videos/rick-and-morty/","data":{"image_added":"true","pictures":["http://i.cdn.turner.com/adultswim/big/img/2015/07/17/Rick%26MortyS02_fbsearchTn.jpg"],"picture":"http://i.cdn.turner.com/adultswim/big/img/2015/07/17/Rick%26MortyS02_fbsearchTn.jpg","link":"http://www.adultswim.com/videos/rick-and-morty/","name":"Watch Rick and Morty on Adult Swim","caption":"www.adultswim.com","description":"Every episode of Rick and Morty is now on AdultSwim.com for free. Rick is a mad scientist who drags his grandson, Morty, on crazy sci-fi adventures. Their escapades often have potentially harmful consequences for their family and the rest of the world. Join Rick and Morty on AdultSwim.com as they trek through alternate dimensions, explore alien planets, and terrorize Jerry, Beth, and Summer.","domain":"www.adultswim.com","type":"link"},"customer_approved":"1","manager_approved":"1","rejection_message":"","created_at":"2020-0413 17:43:29","created_by":"admin","created_by_id":"1","created_by_name":"John Admin"},{"id":"4","schedule":"2020-0424 17:00:00","network":"facebook","network_name":"TestFacebookPage","network_thumb":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17634406_1854330461448271_6787736791983791423_n.jpg?oh=e4c3a3573c0fc59359422cfd66a3865a&oe=598721E7","message":"Test Post 4 (text, pending)","data":[],"customer_approved":"0","manager_approved":"1","rejection_message":"","created_at":"2020-0413 17:43:48","created_by":"admin","created_by_id":"1","created_by_name":"John Admin"},{"id":"5","schedule":"2020-0426 19:00:00","network":"facebook","network_name":"TestFacebookPage","network_thumb":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17634406_1854330461448271_6787736791983791423_n.jpg?oh=e4c3a3573c0fc59359422cfd66a3865a&oe=598721E7","message":"Test Post 5 (picture, pending)","data":[],"customer_approved":"0","manager_approved":"1","rejection_message":"","created_at":"2020-0413 17:44:03","created_by":"admin","created_by_id":"1","created_by_name":"John Admin"},{"id":"6","schedule":"2020-0428 21:00:00","network":"facebook","network_name":"TestFacebookPage","network_thumb":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17634406_1854330461448271_6787736791983791423_n.jpg?oh=e4c3a3573c0fc59359422cfd66a3865a&oe=598721E7","message":"Test Post 6 (link, pending) https://www.reddit.com/","data":{"image_added":"true","pictures":["https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/2Hwaff37fC4f37j-3orrbjVAOVBChqbdm_dXeIhjlNw.jpg"],"picture":"https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/2Hwaff37fC4f37j-3orrbjVAOVBChqbdm_dXeIhjlNw.jpg","link":"https://www.reddit.com/","name":"reddit: the front page of the internet","caption":"www.reddit.com","description":"reddit: the front page of the internet","domain":"www.reddit.com","type":"link"},"customer_approved":"0","manager_approved":"1","rejection_message":"","created_at":"2020-0413 17:44:19","created_by":"admin","created_by_id":"1","created_by_name":"John Admin"}],"total":"6"};

var ListItemModel = Backbone.Model.extend();
var ListItemCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: ListItemModel,
    total: 0,
    
    parse: function(data) {
        this.total = data.total;
        return data.posts;
    }
});

var c = new ListItemCollection(TESTDATA, {parse: true});
var states = c.countBy(function(model) {
    var manager = +model.get("manager_approved"), 
        customer = +model.get("customer_approved");

    if ((manager === -1) || (customer === -1)) return 'rejected';
    if ((manager === 1) && (customer === 1)) return 'approved';
    return 'pending';
});

console.log(states);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
```